# Callkit in ios 10.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

```
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"+918801234567",@"+ 918801234568", nil];
```

how to pass arr to CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumbers[]

Comment: How to pass the above array which will be there in some viewController to CALLKIT class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass multiple phone numbers (for example, stored in the NSArray you mentioned), enumerate the list of phone numbers and call

```
-[CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:]
```

passing each number to the system. Bear in mind, the phone numbers must be sorted in numerically ascending order.