# convert NSArray to CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

Convert NSArray to C Array.

```
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"+918801234567",@"+ 918801234568", nil];
```

how to pass arr to CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumbers[]

Comment: Looks like you both have same task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097841/callkit-in-ios-10-0

Comment: You need to simply pass an array of int64, not strings; so,  `[918801234567,9188011234568]`

Comment: how to pass (NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"+918801234567",@"+ 918801234568", nil];) to CXCallkit class from viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Take `unsignedLongLongValue` of your phone numbers, not `NSString`.
Check [Callkit referance](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit?language=objc#2624905).